# Would an index improve the performance/reduce the cost of a MS SQL Dependency

Tags: sql-server, performance, sqldependency

We have a table in a SQL 2012 Database that contains a field called `LastModifiedDateUtc(DateTime)` which we update on any UPDATE queries by `LastModifiedDateUtc=GETUTCDATE()`

We use a SQLDependency to monitor for changes to this field for the subset of rows that we are interested in using a normal SELECT query - for example `SELECT MyTable.LastModifiedDateUtc FROM dbo.MyTable WHERE ID>=1 and ID<=1000`

This all works really well and performance itself is good.

At present the `LastModifiedDateUtc` is not included in any of the tables Indexes, so my question is whether it's worth adding an index that includes the `ID` and `LastModifiedDateUtc` fields to improve performance at all?

From the information I can find there is a suggestion that the performance cost of using a SQLDependency is the same as adding a second index, so would it use our own Index, or would it always use it's own in which case the UPDATE/INSERT cost of our own index would seem wasted?

Comment: Any reason you don't just, you know, test it? My money is on "no, this index would not be used", but it would take someone else longer to set up a representative test situation and evaluate it than it would you.

Comment: If that column isn't part of your where predicate adding the index is pointless. Indexes are used to find rows which you are doing through a different predicate.

Comment: Hi @JeroenMostert - I can't think of a way of testing the performance of a SQLDependency - i can test the performance of the Query that is executed by the Command that is used to create the dependency, but is there a way to watch the performance of the dependency that is sitting there using triggers to look for the  `LastModifiedDateUtc' field being changed?

Comment: @SeanLange - i wondered that, but didn't know if internally the SQL Triggers that are actually watching the changes would find it easier watching an index than watching the table?

Of course this is based on my understanding of the behaviour/use of SQLDependency is that it effectively gives you a notification saying "You know that query you asked a while ago? Well, if you asked again NOW you'ld get a different result"

Comment: If you can't think of *any* way to observe the difference, then surely the performance is irrelevant? SQL Server exposes plenty of counters to monitor its performance if load is a concern, but your one paltry query is unlikely to rock the boat in any case. On a less philosophical note: if my understanding is correct, effectively, the engine builds an indexed view mechanism (not an actual index) to actually evaluate the changes. Meaning, the performance of *any* query that actually supports notification is more or less constant: it's always one (semi-constant time) evaluation of the condition.